# Ionic 2, can't generate image (icons) because the source image is too small

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I use cli to generate icon and splash screen, for icon i used 192*192 px and when i run the command icons are not generated, the notification says image can not be generated because the source image is too small. But the size i used is the one recommended at ionic forum (192*192 px).am really stuck, any help please ..

Answer (score 0):

the icon should be at least 1024*1024px and the splashscreen should be 2732*2732px [cordova resources](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/cordova/resources/)